# Pycharm doesn't create pip when I create a virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I tried created a project with virtualenv setting in pycharm. I see pip is missing in the virtual env that was created by pycharm. Could someone help me with fix it.
My python version is python3.6.5 and pycharm 2018.1

When I created a virtualenv from terminal it does create a pip ad works fine. I'm assuming thats something to do with pycharm setting that I'm missing

Comment: Activate the venv PyCharm created, run `ls -l $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin | grep pip`, what is the result?

Answer (score -2):

To install pip, download this script and run it with python. 
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

If pip still doesn't show up, it is likely an environment variable issue.